# How to prepare plan for Governance for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, governance

I am trying to find Governance plan or Governance template for SharePoint online. I know governance is not a standard concept to dealt with. At least can i get some good documentation or template saying that what topics needs to be covered ?
And also any training tools available for governance?

Comment: Can you share your experience? Were you able to put something together?

Comment: Nope. It is so big and not clear topic. There is no generalized statement for this

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

For example, refer to  a good article regarding governance (it can be helpful for understanding): [SharePoint Governance Planning](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39184.sharepoint-governance-planning.aspx?Sort=MostUseful&PageIndex=1)

Here is an article regarding SharePoint 2016 (which is close to Online):
[Governance Planning in SharePoint Server 2016] https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt631711(v=office.16).aspx

And another one: [What is governance in SharePoint?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263356(v=office.16).aspx)

An old one (but useful) article: [Plan governance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263341(v=office.12).aspx)

Also refer to special articles regarding Microsoft online services:

[Security and Compliance in SharePoint Online and OneDrive for Business](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wbaer/2017/03/13/security-and-compliance-in-sharepoint-online-and-onedrive-for-business/)

[Office 365 Trust center](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-trust-center-welcome?legRedir=true&CorrelationId=de8d945b-65d3-41bc-b5a5-41d503131554)

Note that a lot of external vendors offer their own solutions for governance:

[AvePoint](https://www.avepoint.com/products/sharepoint-governance/)

[Metalogix](https://www.metalogix.com/solution/sharepoint-security-information-governance)

Here's an example of Governance Guide: [Governance guide for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25201)

In fact, governance is a complex (and complicated) term which includes planning (ie. architecture, establishing services, digital asset management), communication with site, content and app owners, workflows, request management, audit, permission management and user accounting (+ storage quotas, expirations and so on), content freshness and archiving, monitoring, tagging, regulation and compliance, solution management, provisioning of sites, lists and libraries, lifecycle management and much more.