# SharePoint Online Governance

Tags: migration, template, online, governance, standard

What should the SharePoint **Online** Governance document address?

I'm aware about a similar SO question, but the [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/230319/13225) is not satsifactory. Also, I found by googling a [template](https://sharepointmaven.com/the-ultimate-sharepoint-governance-template/) suggested by a consultant, but I'm looking for an unbiased - maybe official template.

The majority of the complex on prem points are simply not applicable and the mechanics of the service are too different.

**We're coming from SP on-premise**

Standalone business service, large farm, thousands of users and site collections, site collections ownership assigned to business users - lots of freedom once you get a site.
Central SP operations team maintaining the farm. Provisioning is pretty straightforward and is done through automation with external process. Same for ownership changing, quota increase. Domain users can be added to any site.
Server-side deployment process following internal code quality standards.

All is controlled internally and based on best practices and experience of years and years of on premise.

**Governing SP online**

How will the governance threshold levels will be affected between: user, site owner, department, company and, the new player, the cloud?

SharePoint architects for on premise need to be aware about a lot of new different contraints and implications - legal, financial, technical, operational and support - when sketching an SP online governance plan; which are the single points of failure which they should consider - license costs, resource costs, data protection, compliance, backwards compatibility in case of migration etc?

My current feeling is that what used to be a very detailed plan for SP on-premise should become a combo of:

- a more vague and more limited in topics scope governance for SP online
- an overarching governance plan for O365 coverin Teams, Groups, SP, Exchange,
  Yammer etc.

And it's also probably a **people** problem - it's expected from experts in SP on-premise to prepare the organizational setup for the online world, usually while they continue their business as usual. Having a side-by-side guide would help immensely.

Comment: This is a very broad question with likely opinionated answers. Can you add some focus to narrow down what specific governance you're after?

Comment: Thanks and sure, let me update.